# Is the memory structure different for each programming language?

Tags: javascript, v8

I learned memory structure of C language. There are code, data, stack, heap area for each purpose. And Os give a process only one code, data, heap area. So all thread share these in the same process. But stack is not shared. Threads have their own stack area. This is a brief summary of the knowledge I know about memory structure with process. I have thought that these four areas exist in any process.

But, I'm confused this structure when I see components of v8 engine.

V8 engine introduce only two components( call stack, heap ).

And people explain call stack a little differently than stack of c.

Stack of c is explained as a memory in which local value is.
Also, The stack area traditionally adjoined the heap and grew in the opposite direction. when the stack pointer met the heap pointer, free memory was exhausted.

However, call stack is described by frame that is about functions.
When a function execute, a frame come in the call stack.
The explanation is ambiguous. Because stack of c is explained in terms of memory. But call stack is not. I want to know that how the frame or call stack relate to physical memory.

So, my questions are

1. Is the memory structure different for each programming language?
2. If 1 is right, where are local values which is in a function(frame) located? ex) heap, ....
3. Where are global variables located?
4. Could you recommend any document to release my curiosity?

Thank you.

Comment: The call stack is a representation of the execution state of your program. It does not relate to stack memory. All programming languages for typical computing hardware have the same 2 memory structures, but most high level programming languages (like javascript) separate the programmer from memory management. Asking for recommendations is a good way to get your question flagged or closed

Comment: Also bear in mind that "C" is a *compiled* language, which typically generates actual executable object-code that will be run directly by the CPU, while many other languages either are *interpreters* or (like Java) produce code that is actually executed (*interpreted ...)* by a runtime engine.  Practical implementations of JavaScript might blur this line even further with "just-in-time compiling."  Interpreters and runtime engines might maintain many different kinds of data-structures which have no corollary in compiled-to-machine-code systems.